# Mimic Sublime Text 2 multi select (multi cursor) in Notepad++ using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

In sublime text 2 you can multi select(cursor) lines by holding ctrl+alt+arrow key (up/down). In notepad++ you can accomplish the same thing by holding ctrl and clicking the additional lines(areas) you would like to edit. I figured I could use a autohotkey script to accomplish the same functionality. So I tried

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^!Down::^Click
```

but each time that I try to load the script I get

Error at Line 2
Line Text: ^Click
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action

the program will exit

then I tried

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^!Down::send ^Click
```

but that shows up as ETXClick in notepad++

What more do I need to get this script to work only for Notepad++

**EDIT**: It appears that autohotkey cannot mimic this behavior in Notepad++
IT

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. You make it sound like you just want it to send a control click, but that most likely won't do what you want unless you specifically move the mouse cursor to a place where it would make sense. Also, I don't see control clicking doing anything in Notepad++ -- you can control drag to select multiple regions, but it doesn't seem to be linewise.

Comment: Good point echristopherson, I never checked this in Notepad++!

Comment: @ echristopherson from what you have indicated autohotkey does not appear to be able to accomplish the same task since I would have to use the mouse still to add additional cursors instead of just using the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Arrow keys.

Comment: Can you please comment it more?

Comment: This is the easiest way to use the multi-line select without having to remove your hands from the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
    ^!Down::Send, ^{Click}
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: are you saying to do this `#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++  
  ^!Down::Send, ^{Click}  
#IfWinActive  `

Comment: yes and as echristopherson pointed out I would still need to move the mouse cursor for this to work. Because I noticed that when taking my hands off the mouse where the cursor was left at is where notepad++ made the new cursor mark in addition to keeping the previous cursor mark.