# Change text contained in an XML file using Python and Notepad++?

Tags: python, xml, notepad++

I have an existing XML file:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8182569

I want to change all the text values of line2, line4, line7,line18,etc..by custom text like that:

```
1:Text1
2:Text2
3:Text3
4:Text4
etc..
```

What would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, how do we call that code? XHTML?

Comment: It's not even XHTML, just just an HTML fragment. And I see no correspondence to that file and what you're asking here? Do you simply want to add line numbers to every line of that file?

Comment: So, here's my problem. I have this fragment of HTML. I need to edit/modify the text multiple times. This text is a specific page of a site and I need to change the text 100 times for 100 pages with a custom text each time. It's like a newsletter template. So I'm looking to find a way to copy and paste the text in one time per page. And not editing each line manually. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the procedure requested is not meant to be done programmatically but the OP is just looking for a workaround to avoid replacing a lot of lines - it may be tedious.

A part from developing a complex python script using `lxml` for instance, you may use another editor like sublime text (http://www.sublimetext.com/) and its multiple cursor capability:

select the lines you want to replace, press `ctrl+shift+l` and paste the multiple lines.

However, if you want to mimic this approach on Notepad++ please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479505/mimic-sublime-text-2-multi-select-multi-cursor-in-notepad-using-autohotkey)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I never used sublime text, I may try it looks like a good alternative.I'm just wondering how the text will be pasted if we select multiple lines? It should be one step process. Interested to try.